# What is Known Regarding the Ancestry of Melchizedek?

Tags: genealogy, melchizedek, shem-ben-noah

Melchizedek, as far as I know, is referred to only twice in the Bible: *Gen. 14:18-20* and *Psalm 110, v. 4.*

QUESTION: What, if anything, is known with a reasonable degree of certainty regarding the ancestry of Melchizedek? Is there anything, perhaps, in the Hebrew literature which might suggest that he was descended from Shem? That perhaps, he *was* Shem?

Note: I am aware of the Wikipedia article on [Melchizedek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melchizedek) which contains some information on this matter.